# Sql insert query not inserting

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, ms-access

I am having trouble getting my sql query to insert data into an access db. If I run the query in sql view in access it inserts fine, so I guess that leaves the error in my code. I am sure I have made a fundamental error and would be grateful if someone could point it out. Thanks

```
Private Sub btnSave_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnSave.Click

        Try

        DBConnection.connect()

            sql = "SELECT MAX([Request no]) from Requests WHERE Customer = '" & cmbCustomer.Text & "' "

            Dim cmd As New OleDb.OleDbCommand

            Dim id As String
            Dim requestor As String = "BT"
            Dim intake As String = "I"
            Dim status As String = "O"

        'cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p1", cmbCustomer.Text)

            cmd.CommandText = sql
            cmd.Connection = oledbCnn
            dr = cmd.ExecuteReader

        While dr.Read()

                id = CStr(dr.Item(0))
                id = CStr(CDbl(id) + 1)


            End While

            sql = "INSERT INTO Requests ([Request no], Customer, Dept, Type, [Service level], [Date-time received], [Received by], [Date-time due], Quantity, [Cust requestor], Status ) " &
            "VALUES ('" & id & "', '" & cmbCustomer.Text.ToUpper & "', '" & cmbDept.Text & "', '" & intake.ToString & "', '" & rbServiceLevel.ToString & "', NOW(), '" & requestor.ToString & "', '" & dtpDateDue.Value & "', '" & txtBoxQuantity.Text & "', '" & requestor.ToString & "', '" & status & "')"

            cmd.Dispose()
            dr.Close()
            oledbCnn.Close()

        Catch ex As Exception

            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)

        End Try

    End Sub
```

DBConnect

```
Imports System.Data.OleDb

Module DBConnection

    Public connetionString As String = My.Settings.storageConnectionString
    Public oledbCnn As New OleDbConnection
    Public oledbCmd As OleDbCommand
    Public dr As OleDbDataReader
    Public sql As String

    Sub connect()

        'connetionString = My.Settings.storageConnectionString
        oledbCnn.ConnectionString = connetionString
        oledbCnn.Open()

    End Sub

End Module
```

Comment: You're not executing your INSERT query, just building it

Comment: How do I amend my code Yuriy. Thanks

Comment: You have to learn how to use parameters to avoid SQL injection.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You problem is that you're building SQL query, but not actually executing it.
Try this:

```
        End While

        dr.Close()

        sql = "INSERT INTO Requests ([Request no], Customer, Dept, Type, [Service level], [Date-time received], [Received by], [Date-time due], Quantity, [Cust requestor], Status ) " & _
        "VALUES ('" & id & "', '" & cmbCustomer.Text.ToUpper & "', '" & cmbDept.Text & "', '" & intake.ToString & "', '" & rbServiceLevel.ToString & "', NOW(), '" & requestor.ToString & "', '" & dtpDateDue.Value & "', '" & txtBoxQuantity.Text & "', '" & requestor.ToString & "', '" & status & "')"

        cmd.CommandText = sql
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()

        cmd.Dispose()
        oledbCnn.Close()

    Catch ex As Exception
```

But listen to @LarsTech - while building SQL command look for [parametrized query](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.oledb.oledbcommand.parameters%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-2) instead of string concatination otherwise you're liable for SQL Injection (someone can spoof data in Textboxes and cause data loss)

Side note: if you're retreiving a single value from DB - instead of `ExecuteReader` look for [ExecuteScalar](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.oledb.oledbcommand.executescalar%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Comment: Yuriy That errors with: Command text was not set for the command object.

Comment: Please verify what is the value of `cmd.CommandText` before executing `cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()` - make sure it's a valid INSERT command

Comment: If you take that text from `cmd.CommandText` as it is and copy/paste it into Access - does it execute without error?

Comment: As an afterthought - `Type` is a reserved word in Acccess - using it as an insert field try `[Type]`

Comment: I have amened that and it still refuses to insert in either access or vb.net. I have checked and rechecked and there are no empty files and zero length is allowed and fields are not required in access.

Comment: This is the result of cmd.CommandText INSERT INTO Requests ([Request no], Customer, Dept, [Type], [Service level], [Date-time received], [Received by], [Date-time due], Quantity, [Cust requestor], Status ) VALUES ('11701', 'TEST', 'TEST', 'I', 'S', '26/12/2013 20:36:52', 'DEMO', '26/12/2013 23:36:52', '1', 'DEMO', 'O',)

Comment: You have an extra comma after `'O'` in values - is this a typo?